# Rotating a rect makes it move in a weird pattern

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-svg

I am attempting to make a rectangle in an svg rotate in place (so around its middle), however this has proven more difficult than I thought. The rectangle instead moves in a weird pattern. This is probably because the rotate origin is wrong however I have not found a way to fix this myself.

I have created an expo for this to demonstrate the problem: https://snack.expo.io/SJqTgyu0N

I would like to keep the style/transition on the rect itself and not move it to the AnimatedG component.

Comment: And what exact animation are you attempting to do?

Comment: Sound like indeed the problem is the rotation origin which is based on the (0,0) point of the viewport. (top, left)

Comment: @JoseVf I would likethe rect to rotate in place (so around its own middle).

Comment: @ApplePearPerson What's the reason you don't want to apply the transition to the AnimatedG component? I achieved the desired behavior applying the transition to that component (https://snack.expo.io/HkMGDXa0E)

Comment: @JoseVf My ultimate goal would be to have for example 10 rects next to each other all rotate in place. I can achieve this with 1 <G> in web so I was hoping to keep a similar SVG style in native. So if the transition were on the <AnimatedG> then either all 10 rects would transform around the same origin or i'd need to create an <AnimatedG> per rect. Would it matter much if I create one <AnimatedG> per rect?

Comment: @ApplePearPerson That could be the easiest solution right now, and you can create a component instead of copy-pasting the same code everywhere. Trying to rotate the Rect produces a really weird behavior. If you rather I can provide an answer with that solution (one AnimatedG per Rect).

Comment: @JoseVf no thats alright I think I can manage that from your expo. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.